# What's the name of the graph operation of connecting two copies of a graph with a perfect matching?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, matching-theory, perfect-matchings

Let $G=(V_1,E_1)$ be a simple graph with vertex set $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ and let $G'=(V_2,E_2)$ be another copy of $G$ with vertex set $\{u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_n\}$. Assume $V_1\cap V_2= \emptyset$.

Let $H=(V,E)$ be a graph with $V=V_1 \cup V_2$ and $E=E_1\cup E_2\cup \{u_1v_1，u_2v_2, \ldots, v_nv_n\}$. It is obtained from $G$ by a graph operation as above. So, is there any name of this operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont't know of a standard name, but it is $G \square K_2$, where $\square$ denotes the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_graphs).

Comment: Not quite, surely. If mapping $u_i$ to $v_i$ is an isomorphism, then it is exactly the Cartesian product with $K_2$, but otherwise it has no particular name.

Comment: Good point.  I assumed the OP meant that $u_i$ is a copy of $v_i$.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily a standard name but [in this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.11706) I and my coauthors called it cloning the graph.